# Creating Microsoft Access Database for multiple departments to submit to

Tags: database, ms-access

I have recently been tasked with the job of creating some sort of a database for which multiple departments could submit forms to and then our data analysts could pull from easily. This is not going to be used in a large capacity. Right now, my idea is to create an Access database on one of our drives and create forms that are connected to said drive for the different departments to fill out. These forms would then be entered into the database and that would be the end of it. I do not have a ton of experience with Access but am fairly experienced with coding. Any suggestions would be great as I am looking to learn as much as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Start with an introductory tutorial and learn Access basics. It should cover database principles and Access functionality and some programming concepts. Db should be a split design. Recommend coding in VBA and not macros.

Comment: You should split the database, Data and Frontend (Forms).  You should also distribute the frontend file so that your users are opening the file from their own PC and not sharing the same file on the shared drive. This is annoying when you need to update the frontend file as the users need to update the file on their PC. So, what I do is create a batch file or HTA that the users run to open the database.  The batch file copies the newest version of the frontend file and then opens it automatically.

Comment: Code to automatically copy the frontend to users works great until IT sets security restrictions so tight it won't work anymore. Very annoying.